# How to read a GPIO input pin in ARM using the Raspberry Pi Pico?

Tags: assembly, arm, cortex-m, led, raspberry-pi-pico

I am starting to learn assembly language and ARM using the raspberry pi pico.

I have even been following the book [RP2040 Assembly Language programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/148427752X) but there is no instruction about how to read an input pin using only assembly.

Here is my set up: I have a push button that send 3,3V when not pressed and 0V when pressed.

I would like to be able to read the different states this has using a GPIO pin but despite looking into the functions of the datasheet (that I barely understand as it's the first time i'm dealing with it), I don't know if what I am doing makes sense.

Here is my code:

```
led_loop:
    @  set the control for the push
    ldr r0, =ctrl2      @  control register for GPIO1 0x40014008
    mov r1, #5          @  Function 5, select SIO for GPIO1 2.19.2
    str r1, [r0]        @  Store function_5 in GPIO1 control register
@ shifts over "1" the number of bits of GPIO pin
    mov r2, #1          @  load a 1 into register 1
    lsl r2, r2, #1      @  move the bit over to align with GPIO1
    ldr r0, =sio_base   @  SIO base 0xd0000000
    str r1, [r0, #0x00000004]   @  0x004 GPIO input enable
    ldr r0, =helloworld
    BL printf
    b led_loop          @  do the loop again

.data
    .align 4
helloworld: .asciz "Hello World %d\n"
```

So far I tried to consult the datasheet but I do not have enough knowledge to recognize if what I am doing is write or wrong.

Comment: is this your first mcu to do this or just another mcu?  if the first then move on to something simpler then come back.   their docs are not good, you have to do a lot of reverse engineering and of course finding scary code just like any other vendor.   the docs are pretty from a formatting and art class stuff, but content is lacking.   try an stm32 nucleo board then come back.    assembly vs C, doesnt matter here its just a programming language you can do anything in asm that you can do in others.   having a printf is quite disturbing.

Comment: control register for GPIO1 0x40014008    0x4001400C is the r/w control register for gpio 1  008 is the status register.

Comment: why are you writing to GPIO_IN?  just read it.  you only need to set the sio function one time.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention but the "HelloWorld" is for debugging purpose, i would like to see if there is any change at the screen when I push the button. I'll read carefully everything you wrote and then I'll comment back. Thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track but appear to be using wrong register values or using them the wrong way.  You have a printf so that is very odd, and implies you have a ton, ton, more code which may or may not be helping.

This is C and uses the led on the original picos, which not sure if that is the case anymore.

```
void PUT32 ( unsigned int, unsigned int );
unsigned int GET32 ( unsigned int );
void DELAY ( unsigned int );

#define RESETS_BASE                 0x4000C000

#define RESETS_RESET_RW             (RESETS_BASE+0x0+0x0000)
#define RESETS_RESET_XOR            (RESETS_BASE+0x0+0x1000)
#define RESETS_RESET_SET            (RESETS_BASE+0x0+0x2000)
#define RESETS_RESET_CLR            (RESETS_BASE+0x0+0x3000)

#define RESETS_RESET_DONE_RW        (RESETS_BASE+0x8+0x0000)
#define RESETS_RESET_DONE_XOR       (RESETS_BASE+0x8+0x1000)
#define RESETS_RESET_DONE_SET       (RESETS_BASE+0x8+0x2000)
#define RESETS_RESET_DONE_CLR       (RESETS_BASE+0x8+0x3000)

#define SIO_BASE                    0xD0000000

#define SIO_GPIO_IN                 (SIO_BASE+0x04)

#define SIO_GPIO_OUT_RW             (SIO_BASE+0x10)
#define SIO_GPIO_OUT_SET            (SIO_BASE+0x14)
#define SIO_GPIO_OUT_CLR            (SIO_BASE+0x18)
#define SIO_GPIO_OUT_XOR            (SIO_BASE+0x1C)

#define SIO_GPIO_OE_RW              (SIO_BASE+0x20)
#define SIO_GPIO_OE_SET             (SIO_BASE+0x24)
#define SIO_GPIO_OE_CLR             (SIO_BASE+0x28)
#define SIO_GPIO_OE_XOR             (SIO_BASE+0x2C)

#define IO_BANK0_BASE               0x40014000

#define IO_BANK0_GPIO25_CTRL_RW     (IO_BANK0_BASE+0x0CC+0x0000)
#define IO_BANK0_GPIO25_CTRL_XOR    (IO_BANK0_BASE+0x0CC+0x1000)
#define IO_BANK0_GPIO25_CTRL_SET    (IO_BANK0_BASE+0x0CC+0x2000)
#define IO_BANK0_GPIO25_CTRL_CLR    (IO_BANK0_BASE+0x0CC+0x3000)

#define IO_BANK0_GPIO1_CTRL_RW     (IO_BANK0_BASE+0x00C+0x0000)
#define IO_BANK0_GPIO1_CTRL_XOR    (IO_BANK0_BASE+0x00C+0x1000)
#define IO_BANK0_GPIO1_CTRL_SET    (IO_BANK0_BASE+0x00C+0x2000)
#define IO_BANK0_GPIO1_CTRL_CLR    (IO_BANK0_BASE+0x00C+0x3000)

int notmain ( void )
{
    unsigned int ra;
    PUT32(RESETS_RESET_CLR,1<<5); //IO_BANK0
    while(1)
    {
        if((GET32(RESETS_RESET_DONE_RW)&(1<<5))!=0) break;
    }
    PUT32(SIO_GPIO_OE_CLR,1<<25);
    PUT32(SIO_GPIO_OUT_CLR,1<<25);
    PUT32(IO_BANK0_GPIO25_CTRL_RW,5); //SIO
    PUT32(SIO_GPIO_OE_SET,1<<25);
    for(ra=0;ra<10;ra++)
    {
        PUT32(SIO_GPIO_OUT_XOR,1<<25);
        DELAY(0x40000);
    }

    PUT32(SIO_GPIO_OE_CLR,1<<1);
    PUT32(SIO_GPIO_OUT_CLR,1<<1);
    PUT32(IO_BANK0_GPIO1_CTRL_RW,5); //SIO
    while(1)
    {
        ra=GET32(SIO_GPIO_IN);
        if(ra&2)
        {
            PUT32(SIO_GPIO_OUT_SET,1<<25);
        }
        else
        {
            PUT32(SIO_GPIO_OUT_CLR,1<<25);
        }
    }
    return(0);
}
```

finding all of those addresses and info strictly from docs is, well...

PUT32 is just a store word and GET32 is just a load word.  and delay is just a counting to zero loop.

GPIO generally defaults/resets to inputs, the clearing of the out/oe and making it an input I probably got directly from their libraries, is it required?  Do not know, could probably read those registers and see.

You do need to release reset on the I/O block for sure, so maybe you are doing that elsewhere.

The above blinks the led 5 times and then goes into a polling loop reading the gpio and isolating gpio 1 if high then light the led if low then not.

Trivial to convert this to asm and should be able to see the differences in what you did and what I did and decide if you need to clear the out/oe settings.  You had wrong addresses and were writing things you should be reading and IO block out of reset at a minimum.